# Constructing SQL statement for ArcPy SearchCursor

Tags: arcpy, sql, cursor

I'm struggling with a real simple cursor problem, and I figure it's probably a syntax issue. But I cannot see what it is.

```
tmpHeader = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@', 'ProjectID','Status','ProjectName','Description','ProjectStartDate','ProjectEndDate']

for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor( "SourceFeatures", str(tmpHeaderHolder)): 
     ...
     ...
```

And then I get this weird error...What puzzles me is the syntax of the resulting SQL statement in the error message

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "loader.py", line 77, in <module>
    for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor( "SourceFeatures", str(tmpHeader)):
RuntimeError: An invalid SQL statement was used. [SELECT ['SHAPE@', 'ProjectID', 'Status', 'ProjectName', 'Description', 'ProjectStartDate', 'ProjectEndDate'], OBJECTID FROM MyFeatureClass]
```

Comment: tmpHeader = line is missing a quote, change tmpHeader = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@', ProjectID','Status', to tmpHeader = ['OID@', 'SHAPE@', 'ProjectID','Status', - the tool thinks you have a where clause because the list is incomplete. Then don't try to str() the 2nd parameter, it's a list of strings as it needs to be.

Comment: Sorry, my bad in preparing the question for here. I have rechecked my tmpheader, also printed it to the console after declaring it. It is right. - I've corrected the question
Still get the error,

Comment: for row in arcpy.da.SearchCursor( "SourceFeatures", tmpHeaderHolder): should then be right, the 2nd parameter is a list of strings.

Comment: Yes, I agree. But it's complaining, and the statement `SELECT ['SHAPE@', 'ProjectID', 'Status', 'ProjectName', 'Description', 'ProjectStartDate', 'ProjectEndDate'], OBJECTID FROM MyFeatureClass` looks ...unusual?

Comment: Yes, it's not SQL. The SELECT and trailing OBJECTID FROM MyFeatureClass is SQL but the rest isn't, it should be in the form FIELD = value. Are you using an enterprise database by any chance? If so this cryptic message could be generated if you're asking for a field that doesn't exist. Try looping through tmpHeader except for SHAPE@ and OID@ and use ListFields to see if the fields exist.

Comment: Why have you cast your list as a string?  I also get an error `An invalid SQL statement was used` when I cast my list of fields as a string, because the tool is expecting a list

Comment: I was getting a `RuntimeError: No support for this geometry type` and thought I was misunderstanding the structure of the field names parameter. (My geometry types are the same at source and target)... but now I'm wondering

Comment: @Maxcot then this is your actual question - remove the cast to `str()` and [edit] your question with the new code and whatever errors you are now getting

Comment: Yep, think I'll just start from the top in a new thread.

Comment: @Maxcot Please don't start a new question, you already have one here and just need to narrow it down to what is your actual question